# TikZ and different alignments on the same line

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=black, rounded corners=2pt, rectangle, bottom color=black!80!white, text width=12cm]
    {text aligned on left margin  t.a. on the right margin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the first part  of the text aligned on left margin of the node and the second on the right, but if I use for the second part the command `\begin{flushright} ... \end{flushright}` I get it on the next line. How can I get the whole text on a single line?

Comment: Does it have to be a single node? You could also use two nodes each 6cm wide, I guess?

Comment: I'd rather to have a single node, but any suggestion is really appreciated. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=black, rounded corners=2pt, rectangle, bottom color=black!80!white,  text width=12cm] {text aligned on left margin \hfill t.a. on the right margin};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```